# Possible to connect to FTP site on LAN using external IP?

Tags: iis, ftp

I've setup an FTP site using IIS 8 and am able to connect to it while inside the LAN using the lcoal ip (192.168.*.*), and connect fine from outside it using my external IP (so I know I setup port forwarding correctly). But I am unable to connect to the site, using the external IP while inside the LAN (it just times out). Is this even possible, and if so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Offtopic for SO, but you'll need to enable NAT loopback on your router.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say probably not.

Port forwarding is part of the NAT translation which should only be done for data coming in  via the external connection.  There would be no reason for internal traffic to be translated.